# Combine two SQL statements where both must be true in many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I'm still quite inexperienced in SQL, and I'm trying to figure out how to combine two requirements for a query.

First the model, to simplify understanding the requirement:

[image]

I need one set of results, getting rows that match either of the values in one list, I'll call this result 1:

```
SELECT * FROM
resource r
inner join 
category_resource cr
on (r.id = cr.resource_id)
where cr.category_id in (8,9)
```

But there is also a second requirement, which I'll call result 2:
A similar statement, but with other values must also be matched (by the same rows) in order for any of these rows to match:

```
SELECT * FROM
resource r
inner join 
category_resource cr
on (r.id = cr.resource_id)
where cr.category_id in (10,11,12)
```

Of course I feel like this is redundant in some way and there should be an easier way to write it all in one statement. But the point of it is, this does NOT fulfil the requirements:

```
SELECT * FROM
resource r
inner join 
category_resource cr
on (r.id = cr.resource_id)
where cr.category_id in (8,9,10,11,12)
```

Since that would just be equivalent to saying match result 1 OR result 2. But what I need is to match result 1 AND result 2. I.e, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
resource r
inner join 
category_resource cr
on (r.id = cr.resource_id)
where cr.category_id in (8,9) AND (10,11,12)
```

But that does not work (probably not correct at all)...

In plain English finally, what I want is to find any resource that has the category 8 OR 9, *AND* has the category 10 OR 11 OR 12.

So how can I accomplish something like this as simply as possible?

EDIT:

I forgot one requirement:

I have to also get the categories that each of the result rows belong to (whether those categories were asked for in the query or not. I.e even if I just ask for any resource belonging to (8 OR 9) AND (10 OR 11 OR 12), if a resource matches, I want to know all the categories it belongs to even if they could include also 13 and 14 for instance...

I had a similar requirement which I got resolved before that pretty much does this:

```
SELECT
  r.id, r.title,
  u.name AS 'created_by',
  GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(CAST(c.id as CHAR),',',c.name,',',c.value) separator ';') AS 'Categories'
FROM
  resource r
  INNER JOIN 
/*Select matching records as a table*/
(SELECT
    resource_id
  FROM
    category_resource
  WHERE
    category_id IN (9,10,11,12,13,14,15)) mr
    ON r.id = mr.resource_id
  INNER JOIN category_resource cr
    ON r.id = cr.resource_id
  INNER JOIN category c
    ON cr.category_id = c.id
  INNER JOIN user u
    ON r.created_by = u.id
GROUP BY r.id;
```

But that statement of course does not incorporate this latest requirement. Can I combine this and get the results including all categories each result belongs to?

The answer from mrjink seems to work perfectly. And I have also tested using the same pattern to add even more criteria along the same lines, and it seems to work great:

```
SELECT
  r.id, r.title,
  u.name AS 'created_by',
  GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(CAST(c.id as CHAR),',',c.name,',',c.value) separator ';') AS 'Categories'
FROM
  resource r
  INNER JOIN 
/*Select matching records as a table*/
  (SELECT
   DISTINCT r.id AS id
  FROM
   resource r
  INNER JOIN
   category_resource cr1 ON (r.id = cr1.resource_id)
  INNER JOIN
   category_resource cr2 ON (r.id = cr2.resource_id)
/*For more criteria, I can just add an inner join here with another alias...*/
INNER JOIN
   category_resource cr3 ON (r.id = cr3.resource_id)
INNER JOIN
   category_resource cr4 ON (r.id = cr4.resource_id)
  WHERE
   cr1.category_id IN (8, 9)
  AND
   cr2.category_id IN (10)
/*and add the corresponding ADD clause here for the same alias...*/
  AND
   cr3.category_id IN (12)
  AND
   cr4.category_id IN (14)) mr

    ON r.id = mr.id
  INNER JOIN category_resource cr
    ON r.id = cr.resource_id
  INNER JOIN category c
    ON cr.category_id = c.id
  INNER JOIN user u
    ON r.created_by = u.id
GROUP BY r.id;
```

This way I can add more criteria programmatically if the user selects them (as is the intention). From what I can see, although this might create really complex SQL statements if one were to write or read them by hand, it seems to work well and does not affect performance in a negative way (if anything, adding more criteria seems to speed it up, presumably because there are less and less hits?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join twice!

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
  r.id, r.title,
  u.name AS 'created_by',
  GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(CAST(c.id as CHAR),',',c.name,',',c.value) separator ';') AS 'Categories'
FROM
  resource r
  INNER JOIN 
/*Select matching records as a table*/

  (SELECT
   DISTINCT r.id AS id
  FROM
   resource r
  INNER JOIN
   category_resource cr1 ON (r.id = cr1.resource_id)
  INNER JOIN
   category_resource cr2 ON (r.id = cr2.resource_id)
  WHERE
   cr1.category_id IN (8, 9)
  AND
   cr2.category_id IN (10, 11, 12)) mr

    ON r.id = mr.id
  INNER JOIN category_resource cr
    ON r.id = cr.resource_id
  INNER JOIN category c
    ON cr.category_id = c.id
  INNER JOIN user u
    ON r.created_by = u.id
GROUP BY r.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great. Could you explain exactly what the joining twice does so I can understand the statement?

Comment: I just edited the question because I realized I had forgotten an important requirement. I believe your answer would work fine, I just need to incorporate the category information for each result in order to be able to use it... Could you please take a look at my edit? Thanks!

Comment: You get all resources, and combine them with all categories (cr1) for those resources, and combine them with all categories (cr2) for those resources. (Yes, that duplication is intentional.) Then you select all resources that match (8,9) and (10,11,12).

Comment: Join once more (maybe on `cr`) but then don't include `cr` in the WHERE clause, so no filtering happens.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any chance you could put that in after your first sample in your answer? I'm afraid it's very hard for me still to do statements this complex...

Comment: @AndersSvensson Like that?

Comment: Well I'm not sure... I got a different result now. Your first statement gave me 2 hits in my sample database, which is correct. But the updated one only gave me 1 hit, and one of the categories was repeated twice in the concatenated string... (10)

Comment: @AndersSvensson like that, perhaps?  Please keep in mind I'm doing this in my head, since I don't have your data, and I can't really  create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), since it's down at the moment.

Comment: Well almost... (I'm amazed you'd be able to get this close in your head though!) There was a "ON r.id = mr.resource_id" in there that gave me an error. I tested removing it, and then I get close to correct results. The only thing is I get some of the categories repeated for each concatenation... I could email you an SQL dump for the sample data if you'd like to test it? If you have an email here at SO that I can send to that is. I'll check.

Comment: Edited once more. :)  And once [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is back, you can test there (and have others test with your data, too).

Comment: Ok, nice. I was just going to post some SQL here that I had made more generic to be able to post it publicly, but I think it works now! I'll test a little more before deciding this is the answer, but it looks great to me. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, I have tested it as much as I can now, and cannot see any problem with it. Please see my edit again, though, I added an example showing how I want to be able to add such criteria programmatically, and it seems to work. Can you confirm that this strategy is fine? I'm not used to creating such complex SQL statements, but from what I can see this is the fastest way I can get this sort of data, so unless there's something blatantly wrong with it... I'll mark this as the answer shortly, but if you could comment on this strategy I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from resource
where id in(
select set1.resource_id from
(select resource_id 
     from category_resource where category_id in (8,9)) set1
join (select resource_id 
     from category_resource where category_id in (10,11,12)) set2
on set1.resource_id = set2.resource_id
group by set1.resource_id);
```

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ce70/5

Comment: Thank you, also a good answer that worked fine too. I needed the category_id in the result though, which I forgot to mention. How would I get that in there?

Comment: If you need the category id in the result use mrjink's approach.